# lxml: add namespace to input file

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, lxml, sbml

I am parsing an xml file generated by an external [program](http://celldesigner.org/). I would then like to add custom annotations to this file, using my own namespace. My input looks as below:

```
<sbml xmlns="http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level2/version4" xmlns:celldesigner="http://www.sbml.org/2001/ns/celldesigner" level="2" version="4">
  <model metaid="untitled" id="untitled">
    <annotation>...</annotation>
    <listOfUnitDefinitions>...</listOfUnitDefinitions>
    <listOfCompartments>...</listOfCompartments>
    <listOfSpecies>
      <species metaid="s1" id="s1" name="GenA" compartment="default" initialAmount="0">
        <annotation>
          <celldesigner:extension>...</celldesigner:extension>
        </annotation>
      </species>
      <species metaid="s2" id="s2" name="s2" compartment="default" initialAmount="0">
        <annotation>
           <celldesigner:extension>...</celldesigner:extension>
        </annotation>
      </species>
    </listOfSpecies>
    <listOfReactions>...</listOfReactions>
  </model>
</sbml>
```

The issue being that lxml only declares namespaces when they are used, which means the declaration is repeated many times, like so (simplified):

```
<sbml xmlns="namespace" xmlns:celldesigner="morenamespace" level="2" version="4">
  <listOfSpecies>
    <species>
      <kjw:test xmlns:kjw="http://this.is.some/custom_namespace"/>
      <celldesigner:data>Some important data which must be kept</celldesigner:data>
    </species>
    <species>
      <kjw:test xmlns:kjw="http://this.is.some/custom_namespace"/>
    </species>
    ....
  </listOfSpecies>
</sbml>
```

Is it possible to force lxml to write this declaration only once in a parent element, such as `sbml` or `listOfSpecies`? Or is there a good reason not to do so? The result I want would be:

```
<sbml xmlns="namespace" xmlns:celldesigner="morenamespace" level="2" version="4"  xmlns:kjw="http://this.is.some/custom_namespace">
  <listOfSpecies>
    <species>
      <kjw:test/>
      <celldesigner:data>Some important data which must be kept</celldesigner:data>
    </species>
    <species>
      <kjw:test/>
    </species>
    ....
  </listOfSpecies>
</sbml>
```

The important problem is that the existing data which is read from a file must be kept, so I cannot just make a new root element (I think?).

EDIT: Code attached below.

```
def annotateSbml(sbml_input):
  from lxml import etree

  checkSbml(sbml_input) # Makes sure the input is valid sbml/xml.

  ns = "http://this.is.some/custom_namespace"
  etree.register_namespace('kjw', ns)

  sbml_doc = etree.ElementTree()
  root = sbml_doc.parse(sbml_input, etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True))
  nsmap = root.nsmap
  nsmap['sbml'] = nsmap[None] # Makes code more readable, but seems ugly. Any alternatives to this?
  nsmap['kjw'] = ns
  ns = '{' + ns + '}'
  sbmlns = '{' + nsmap['sbml'] + '}'

  for species in root.findall('sbml:model/sbml:listOfSpecies/sbml:species', nsmap):
    species.append(etree.Element(ns + 'test'))

  sbml_doc.write("test.sbml.xml", pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)

  return
```

Comment: @Marcin: done. Any tips?

Comment: @mzjin my input is contains everything except the `<kjw:test/>` tags. The aim is to insert such tags (or similar, e.g. `kjw:score` or `kjw:length`) to each species in this list.

Does this make sense, or should I post the whole file (figured my original question was long enough as it is)?

Comment: @mzjin Ah sorry, oversimplified that a bit. Yes it does indeed contain model tags. I've used the `sbml:model` tags together with `nsmap['sbml'] = nsmap[None]` so the parser properly substitutes the namespace in model with the root namespace, which it doesn't seem to otherwise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Modifying the namespace mapping of a node is not possible in lxml. See [this open ticket](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/555602) that has this feature as a wishlist item.

It originated from [this thread](https://mailman-mail5.webfaction.com/pipermail/lxml/20100323/thread.html#13258) on the lxml mailing list, where a [workaround replacing the root node](https://mailman-mail5.webfaction.com/pipermail/lxml/20100323/013260.html) is given as an alternative. There are some issues with replacing the root node though: see the ticket above.

I'll put the suggested root replacement workaround code here for completeness:

```
>>> DOC = """<sbml xmlns="http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level2/version4" xmlns:celldesigner="http://www.sbml.org/2001/ns/celldesigner" level="2" version="4">
...   <model metaid="untitled" id="untitled">
...     <annotation>...</annotation>
...     <listOfUnitDefinitions>...</listOfUnitDefinitions>
...     <listOfCompartments>...</listOfCompartments>
...     <listOfSpecies>
...       <species metaid="s1" id="s1" name="GenA" compartment="default" initialAmount="0">
...         <annotation>
...           <celldesigner:extension>...</celldesigner:extension>
...         </annotation>
...       </species>
...       <species metaid="s2" id="s2" name="s2" compartment="default" initialAmount="0">
...         <annotation>
...            <celldesigner:extension>...</celldesigner:extension>
...         </annotation>
...       </species>
...     </listOfSpecies>
...     <listOfReactions>...</listOfReactions>
...   </model>
... </sbml>"""
>>> 
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> NS = "http://this.is.some/custom_namespace"
>>> tree = etree.ElementTree(element=None, file=StringIO(DOC))
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> nsmap = root.nsmap
>>> nsmap['kjw'] = NS
>>> new_root = etree.Element(root.tag, nsmap=nsmap)
>>> new_root[:] = root[:]
>>> new_root.append(etree.Element('{%s}%s' % (NS, 'test')))
>>> new_root.append(etree.Element('{%s}%s' % (NS, 'test')))

>>> print etree.tostring(new_root, pretty_print=True)
<sbml xmlns:celldesigner="http://www.sbml.org/2001/ns/celldesigner" xmlns:kjw="http://this.is.some/custom_namespace" xmlns="http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level2/version4"><model metaid="untitled" id="untitled">
    <annotation>...</annotation>
    <listOfUnitDefinitions>...</listOfUnitDefinitions>
    <listOfCompartments>...</listOfCompartments>
    <listOfSpecies>
      <species metaid="s1" id="s1" name="GenA" compartment="default" initialAmount="0">
        <annotation>
          <celldesigner:extension>...</celldesigner:extension>
        </annotation>
      </species>
      <species metaid="s2" id="s2" name="s2" compartment="default" initialAmount="0">
        <annotation>
           <celldesigner:extension>...</celldesigner:extension>
        </annotation>
      </species>
    </listOfSpecies>
    <listOfReactions>...</listOfReactions>
  </model>
<kjw:test/><kjw:test/></sbml>
```

Comment: For future reference this requires a small alteration (on Python 3.2 at least), otherwise gives a TypeError from `**root.nsmap` when it hits the `None:'namespace'` as `None` is not a string. Using `nsmap = root.nsmap;` `nsmap['kjw'] = NS;` `new_root = etree.Element(root.tag, nsmap = nsmap);` works.

Comment: you also need to copy attrib, text, and (unlikely, but just for completness) tail. `nsmap=dict(kjw=NS, nsmap=nsmap))` is wrong; it should be just `nsmap=nsmap`

Answer (score 8):

I know this is old question, but it still valid and as of lxml 3.5.0, there is probably better solution to this problem:

> `cleanup_namespaces()` accepts a new argument `top_nsmap` that moves definitions of the provided prefix-namespace mapping to the top of the tree.

So now the namespace map can be moved up with simple call to this:

```
nsmap = {'kjw': 'http://this.is.some/custom_namespace'}
etree.cleanup_namespaces(root, top_nsmap=nsmap)
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than dealing directly with the raw XML you could also look toward [LibSBML](http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML), a library for manipulating SBML documents with language bindings for, among others, python. There you would use it like this:

```
>>> from libsbml import *
>>> doc = readSBML('Dropbox/SBML Models/BorisEJB.xml')
>>> species = doc.getModel().getSpecies('MAPK')
>>> species.appendAnnotation('<kjw:test xmlns:kjw="http://this.is.some/custom_namespace"/>')
0
>>> species.toSBML()
'<species id="MAPK" compartment="compartment" initialConcentration="280" boundaryCondition="false">\n  <annotation>\n
 <kjw:test xmlns:kjw="http://this.is.some/custom_namespace"/>\n  </annotation>\n</species>'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you temporarily add a namespaced attribute to the root node, that does the trick.

```
ns = '{http://this.is.some/custom_namespace}'

# add 'kjw:foobar' attribute to root node
root.set(ns+'foobar', 'foobar')

# add kjw namespace elements (or attributes) elsewhere
... get child element species ...
species.append(etree.Element(ns + 'test'))

# remove temporary namespaced attribute from root node
del root.attrib[ns+'foobar']
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function  to add a namespace to the root element:

```py
def addns(tree, alias, uri):                
    root = tree.getroot()
    nsmap = root.nsmap
    nsmap[alias] = uri
    new_root = etree.Element(root.tag, attrib=root.attrib, nsmap=nsmap)
    new_root[:] = root[:]
    return new_root.getroottree()
```

After applying this function, you get a new tree, but you can probably change the tree instance from the single objet from which you access the tree
 <sub>*... as you have a strong OO design!*</sub>.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the root element to add 'kjw' to its nsmap. Then xmlns declaration would be only in the root element.