# Comment out an element using lxml

Tags: python, lxml

Is it possible to comment out an xml element with python's lxml while preserving the original element rendering inside the comment? I tried the following

```
elem.getparent().replace(elem, etree.Comment(etree.tostring(elem, pretty_print=True)))
```

but `tostring()` adds the namespace declaration.

Comment: What namespace declaration? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: mzjn: xmlns="foo" etc. In the original xml these declarations are inherited from the root element and are not explicitly present in the children. tostring(), of course, doesn't know that.

Comment: OK, I understand. But I still think that it is reasonable to request a complete example that demonstrates the problem. Now I have provided an example in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace of the commented-out element is inherited from the root element. Demo:

```
from lxml import etree

XML = """
<root xmlns='foo'>
 <a>
  <b>AAA</b>
 </a>
</root>"""

root = etree.fromstring(XML)
b = root.find(".//{foo}b")
b.getparent().replace(b, etree.Comment(etree.tostring(b)))
print etree.tostring(root)
```

Result:

```
<root xmlns="foo">
 <a>
  <!--<b xmlns="foo">AAA</b>
 --></a>
</root>
```

Manipulating namespaces is often harder than you might suspect. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31870245/407651.

My suggestion here is to use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), which in practice does not really care about namespaces (`soup.find('b')` returns the `b` element even though it is in the `foo` namespace).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

soup = BeautifulSoup(XML, "xml")
b = soup.find('b')
b.replace_with(Comment(str(b)))
print soup.prettify()
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root mlns="foo">
 <a>
  <!--<b>AAA</b>-->
 </a>
</root>
```