# How to comment entire block and single tag of xml in python?

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces, elementtree

How to comment an entire specific block and a particular tag of xml in python ?
In below xml, there are many `<list>` tags.
1) Have to comment entire block `<list> {some_data}</list>`, where `<list name="list_name1">`
2) If you observe `<list name="list_name3">` , there are 2 `<p> tags` in a `<item>`.

```
<p name="address1">some/address-3</p><p name="address1_1">some/address-1_1</p>
```

Here, have to comment second `<p> tag`, ie.,`<p name="address1_1">some/address-1_1</p>`, all such instances.

```
How can we achieve this in python ?
Which is best xml module in python ?
```

**sample_file.xml**

```
    <raml xmlns="abcd.xsd" version="0.1">
    <newData type="hw">
        <header>
          <log action="create" dateTime="2020-01-15T16:45:12.001Z" />
        </header>
        <sampleObject class="com.abcd.efgh:VASDF" distName="some_unique_name" operation="update" version="HDGEKB_8363_845"> 
            <p name="p_name1">true</p>
            <list name="list_name1">
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-1</p>
                    <p name="value">some/value-1</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-2</p>
                    <p name="value">some/value-2</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-3</p>
                    <p name="value">some/value-3</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-4</p>
                    <p name="value">some/value-4</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-5</p>
                    <p name="value">some/value-5</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-6</p>
                    <p name="value">some/value-6</p>
                </item>
            </list>
            <list name="list_name2">
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-1</p>
                    <p name="value">1</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-2</p>
                    <p name="value">2</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-3</p>
                    <p name="value">3</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-4</p>
                    <p name="value">4</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-5</p>
                    <p name="value">5</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-6</p>
                    <p name="value">6</p>
                </item>
            </list>
            <list name="list_name3">
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-1</p>
                    <p name="address1_1">some/address-1_1</p>
                    <p name="value">1</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1_1">some/address-1_1</p>
                    <p name="value">1_1</p>
                <item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-2</p>
                    <p name="value">2</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-3</p>
                    <p name="address1_1">some/address-1_1</p>
                    <p name="value">3</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1_1">some/address-1_1</p>
                    <p name="value">3_3</p>
                <item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-4</p>
                    <p name="value">4</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-5</p>
                    <p name="value">5</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-6</p>
                    <p name="value">6</p>
                </item>
             </list>                                                                
        </sampleObject> 
    </newData>

</raml>
```

**output_file.xml** , should look like below

```
<raml xmlns="abcd.xsd" version="0.1">
    <newData type="hw">
        <header>
          <log action="create" dateTime="2020-01-15T16:45:12.001Z" />
        </header>
        <sampleObject class="com.abcd.efgh:VASDF" distName="some_unique_name" operation="update" version="HDGEKB_8363_845"> 
            <p name="p_name1">true</p>
            <!--<list name="list_name1">
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-1</p>
                    <p name="value">some/value-1</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-2</p>
                    <p name="value">some/value-2</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-3</p>
                    <p name="value">some/value-3</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-4</p>
                    <p name="value">some/value-4</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-5</p>
                    <p name="value">some/value-5</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-6</p>
                    <p name="value">some/value-6</p>
                </item>
            </list> -->
            <list name="list_name2">
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-1</p>
                    <p name="value">1</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-2</p>
                    <p name="value">2</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-3</p>
                    <p name="value">3</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-4</p>
                    <p name="value">4</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-5</p>
                    <p name="value">5</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-6</p>
                    <p name="value">6</p>
                </item>
            </list>
            <list name="list_name3">
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-1</p>
                    <!--<p name="address1_1">some/address-1_1</p>-->
                    <p name="value">1</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1_1">some/address-1_1</p>
                    <p name="value">1_1</p>
                <item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-2</p>
                    <p name="value">2</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-3</p>
                    <!--<p name="address1_1">some/address-1_1</p>-->
                    <p name="value">3</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1_1">some/address-1_1</p>
                    <p name="value">3_3</p>
                <item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-4</p>
                    <p name="value">4</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-5</p>
                    <p name="value">5</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <p name="address1">some/address-6</p>
                    <p name="value">6</p>
                </item>
             </list>                                                                
        </sampleObject> 
    </newData>

</raml>
```

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44416111/407651

Comment: *"Which is best xml module in python?"* If by "best" you mean "has the most features", then my answer would be [lxml](http://lxml.de/index.html).

Comment: Thanks @mzjn , How can we comment that entire block ? and block tag containing only address1_1, where both address1 and address1_1 (not where alone address1_1 present. Refer section <list name="list_name3">). Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*lxml* is able to replace any element with another element, including comment,
but unfortunately if you create the text of this comment from an existing element,
*lxml* copies the default namespace again to the comment text.

So instead of *lxml* I decided to use *BeautifulSoup*, which treats namespaces
more "leniently".

Try the below code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('Input.xml'), 'xml')
for elem in soup.findAll('list'):
    elem.replace_with(Comment(str(elem)))
print(soup.prettify())
```

For your input XML, shortened a bit, I got:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<raml version="0.1" xmlns="abcd.xsd">
  <newData type="hw">
    <header>
      <log action="create" dateTime="2020-01-15T16:45:12.001Z"/>
    </header>
    <sampleObject class="com.abcd.efgh:VASDF" distName="some_unique_name" operation="update" version="HDGEKB_8363_845">
      <p name="p_name1">true</p>
<!--<list name="list_name1">
<item>
<p name="address1">some/address-1</p>
<p name="value">1</p>
</item>
<item>
<p name="address1">some/address-2</p>
<p name="value">2</p>
</item>
</list>-->
<!--<list name="list_name2">
<item>
<p name="address1">some/address-3</p>
<p name="value">3</p>
</item>
<item>
<p name="address1">some/address-4</p>
<p name="value">4</p>
</item>
</list>-->
    </sampleObject>
  </newData>
</raml>
```

## Edit

If you want to comment out only one *list* element (e.g. with *name*
attribute set to 'list_name1'), the correction is simple:

*findAll* has another parameter, namely *attrs* (a dictionary),
where you can pass any attribute names / values to narrow down the selection.

In this case change the loop to:

```
for elem in soup.findAll('list', attrs={'name': 'list_name1'}):
    elem.replace_with(Comment(str(elem)))
```

To only delete selected elements, the name of a method to do it is
less intuitive, namely it is *decompose*.

To do it, run:

```
for elem in soup.findAll('list', attrs={'name': 'list_name1'}):
    elem.decompose()
```

## Edit following the comment about XML prefix

One recipe to remove XML prefix is to call *BeautifulSoup* **without** the
second *xml* argument.

But then the root element in the output is *html*, containing inside *body*
element and *raml* element is inside it.

So to drop these 2 "outer" elements, change the code to:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('Input.xml'))
for elem in soup.findAll('list'):
    elem.replace_with(Comment(str(elem)))
print(soup.html.body.raml.prettify())
```

Also e.g. `<p>` element is kept in a **single** line.

A bit "dirty" solution, but hopefully leading to the expected result.

Comment: Thank you. How to comment only list-block where name="list_name1" ?

Comment: And also, can we delete the same ? like, delete only <list> where name="list_name1"

Comment: elem.replace_with(Comment(str(elem))) , not commenting in file. Instead, it's printing that entire block.

Comment: elem.decompose() , not deleting that entire block

Comment: Note that *findAll* in the last example contains *attrs={'name': 'list_name1'}* parameter,
so only this **one** instance of *list* is deleted.
If you drop *attrs* parameter, then **all** *list* elements will be deleted.
Try on your own computer.

Comment: @Valdi_Bro : Understood that. Do we need to externally comment in the file ? Because, I tried "elem.replace_with(Comment(str(elem)))", it prints that particular block on console but never commented in the actual file. Could you help me ?

Comment: @Valdi_Bro : have you tried that ? could you help me ?

Comment: neither deleting nor commenting.

Comment: All what my code performs are changes in the XML tree loaded into memory. So far no changes have been made to the input file. I think, the first try should be to save the changed XML tree in **another** file (don't overwrite the original file till you are sure that these changes are OK). Only after that (after you see the changes are correct) you can change your code to overwrite the original file.

Comment: Thanks @Valdi_Bo.  It works perfectly. 
Is it possible to check if it's commented already ? If commented already no need to comment. If not commented, then comment. Possible ?

Comment: I think it is not needed. Comment node is just a comment and whatever text inside it (even looking as an XML tag) will not be parsed as any XML tag.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> , this tag is added at the beginning. Can we remove this ?

Comment: And also, structure of xml changes. Say for example above <p name="address1">some/address-1</p> (all in one line). In output file, this single line printed in three lines. Can we retain original alignment/style/structure ?

Comment: writelines(data, xml_declaration=False) takes no keyword arguments.

Comment: @Vladi_Bo :  Possible to remove <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  and retain original xml file indentation/style/alignement ?

Comment: could remove that <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  by using "soup.decode_contents()". now to retain original indentation or anything similar pretty-print.