# How to remove attribute from root element in Python xml etree ElementTree

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, elementtree, xml-sitemap

My file contains the following data:

Original:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> <url> <changefreq>daily</changefreq> <loc>http://www.example.com</loc></url></urlset>
```

Expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset> <url> <changefreq>daily</changefreq> <loc>http://www.example.com</loc></url></urlset>
```

I use etree to parse the file and I want to remove the attribute from the root element 'urlset'

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("/Users/hsyang/Downloads/VI-0-11-14-2016_20.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

print root.attrib
>> {}

root.attrib.pop("xmlns", None)

print root.attrib
>> {}
ET.tostring(root)
```

I thought I was supposed to get {xmlns:"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"} when i print root.attrib the first time but I got an empty dictionary. Can someone help?

Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"` looks like a regular attribute but it is a special case, namely a namespace declaration.

Removing, adding, or modifying namespaces can be quite hard. "Normal" attributes are stored in an element's writable `attrib` property. Namespace mappings on the other hand are not readily available via the API (in the lxml library, elements do have a `nsmap` property, but it is read-only).

I suggest a simple textual search-and-replace operation, similar to the answer to [Modify namespaces in a given xml document with lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20947162/407651). Something like this:

```
with open("input.xml", "r") as infile, open("output.xml", "w") as outfile:
    data = infile.read()
    data = data.replace(' xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"', '')
    outfile.write(data)
```

See also [How to insert namespace and prefixes into an XML string with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31864133/407651).

Answer (score 0):

In standard library [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) there is no special method to remove an attribute, but all attributes are stored in a `attrib` which is a `dict` and any attribute can be removed from `attrib` as a key from a `dict`:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    tree = ET.parse(file_path)
    root = tree.getroot()      

    print(root.attrib)  # {'xyz': '123'}

    root.attrib.pop("xyz", None)  # None is to not raise an exception if xyz does not exist

    print(root.attrib)  # {}

    ET.tostring(root)
    '<urlset> <url> <changefreq>daily</changefreq> <loc>http://www.example.com</loc></url></urlset>'
```

Comment: the real key-value of the root attribute in my file is actually <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> but for simplicity i swapped it with xyz="123". I was wondering if xmlns means anything special in XML so that it's not treated as regular attribute keys here...just my  non-developer suspicion.

Comment: Yes, `xmlns` has special meaning in `xml`: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp
So you have to remove that attribute carefully

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Just wanted to clarify tho - I was using xml.etree.ElementTree. I tried both methods you suggested and both methods (.pop, strip_attributes) raised errors; I think in your examples you were referring to lxml.etree. I tried to find any method that does the same in xml.etree but could not find any.

Comment: You are right, examples were for `lxml`. Updated for  `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

Comment: But this method can't be applied to `xmlns`, since `xmlns` is not stored in `attrib` attribute.

Comment: Appreciate the edits. I tried what you suggested and updated my post, but it seems that root.attrib was an empty dictionary to begin with.

Comment: As I wrote in last comment, `xmlns` is not stored in `attrib`)