# Default namespace and prefixed namespace sharing same URI - Need to remove default namespace URI alone from element using python

Tags: xml, python-2.7, lxml, xml-namespaces

The default Namespace and prefixed namespace shares same URI.

**XML :**

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema" xmlns:sch="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema">
<sch:requesterName>cusadmin</sch:requesterName>
<sch:requesterLanguage>100</sch:requesterLanguage>
<sch:requestOrigin>QAOffshore</sch:requestOrigin>
<QuestionId>472</QuestionId>
</Envelope>
```

I need to remove the default namespace alone from the element tag. since both default and prefixed namespace uri are same, the following code removes prefixed namespace too.:(

**My code:**

```
from lxml import etree
import re
df_temp1=[]
root_ns=etree.iterparse(open("D:\\Sample_data\\XML\\data_stack.xml",'r'),events=['start-ns'])
for _, node in root_ns:
    if(node[0]==''):
        df_temp1.append(node[1])
tree=etree.parse(open("D:\\Sample_data\\XML\\data_stack.xml",'r'))
for e in tree.iter():
        #if element has default namespace--remove the default namespace
        if '{' in e.tag:
            names = e.tag.split('}', 1)[0]
            names1=re.sub("[\{\}]","",names)
            if(names1 in df_temp1):
                e.tag=e.tag.split('}', 1)[1]
        print e.tag
```

**Output:**

```
Envelope
requesterName
requesterLanguage
requestOrigin
QuestionId
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Envelope
{http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema}requesterName
{http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema}requesterLanguage
{http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema}requestOrigin
QuestionId
```

Any idea on how to get this expected output?

Comment: If the only change is that the default namespace declaration (`xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema"`) is removed, then the root element won't be in any namespace, and `{http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema}Envelope` cannot be part of the expected result.

Comment: @mzjn yes, you are right.I have changed the expected result...

Comment: I suggest a simple textual search and replace operation, similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40978913/407651.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove your namespace prefix "**sch**" you have to register the namespace like below-

```
ET.register_namespace('', "http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema")
```