# lxml override root element namespace

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, lxml

I have an xml document that resembles the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
        <document xmlns='https://www.example.com' xmlns:asi='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
            <articleID>1234567890</articleID>
            <article>
                <title>Some random title</title>
            </article>
        </document>
```

Using lxml, I want to be able to override/replace the root element's namespace/nsmap so that it resembles the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
        <document xmlns='https://www.somethingelse.com' xmlns:asi='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
            <articleID>1234567890</articleID>
            <article>
                <title>Some random title</title>
            </article>
        </document>
```

How could I accomplish that using lxml?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655130/changing-element-namespace-in-lxml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [changing element namespace in lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655130/changing-element-namespace-in-lxml)