# how can i remove ns from xml in python?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have a xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:epp xmlns:ns0="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" 
 xmlns:ns1="http://epp.nic.ir/ns/contact-1.0">
   <ns0:command>
      <ns0:check>
         <ns1:check>
            <ns1:id>ex61-irnic</ns1:id>
            <ns1:id>ex999-irnic</ns1:id>
            <ns1:authInfo>
               <ns1:pw>1487441516170712</ns1:pw>
            </ns1:authInfo>
         </ns1:check>
      </ns0:check>
      <ns0:clTRID>TEST-12345</ns0:clTRID>
   </ns0:command>
</ns0:epp>
```

I want to change it with python 3 to be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
   <command>
      <check>
         <check>
            <id>ex61-irnic</id>
            <id>ex999-irnic</id>
            <authInfo>
               <pw>1487441516170712</pw>
            </authInfo>
         </check>
      </check>
      <clTRID>TEST-12345</clTRID>
   </command>
</epp>
```

i tried to remove ns with objectify.deannotate from lxml module.
but it didn't work.
could you please help me to reach my aim ?

Comment: Just do a simple find and replace/remove for the strings 'ns1:' or 'ns0:'

Comment: ...which will of course break things if the string "ns1:" is included somewhere other than as a namespace specifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a combination of [Remove namespace and prefix from xml in python using lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159221/remove-namespace-and-prefix-from-xml-in-python-using-lxml), which shows how to modify the namespace of an element, and [lxml: add namespace to input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346480/lxml-add-namespace-to-input-file), which shows how to reset the top namespace map.

The code is a little hacky (I'm particularly suspicious of whether or not it's kosher to use the `_setroot` method), but it seems to work:

```
from lxml import etree

inputfile = 'data.xml'
target_ns = 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0'
nsmap = {None: target_ns}

tree = etree.parse(inputfile)
root = tree.getroot()

# here we set the namespace of all elements to target_ns
for elem in root.getiterator():
    tag = etree.QName(elem.tag)
    elem.tag = '{%s}%s' % (target_ns, tag.localname)

# create a new root element and set the namespace map, then
# copy over all the child elements    
new_root = etree.Element(root.tag, nsmap=nsmap)
new_root[:] = root[:]

# create a new elementtree with new_root so that we can use the
# .write method.
tree = etree.ElementTree()
tree._setroot(new_root)

tree.write('done.xml',
           pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

Given your sample input, this produces in `done.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0"><command>
      <check>
         <check>
            <id>ex61-irnic</id>
            <id>ex999-irnic</id>
            <authInfo>
               <pw>1487441516170712</pw>
            </authInfo>
         </check>
      </check>
      <clTRID>TEST-12345</clTRID>
   </command>
</epp>
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files such as removing namespaces. Python's third-party module, `lxml`, can run XSLT 1.0 scripts. And because XSLT scripts *are* XML files, you can parse from file or string like any XML. No loops or conditional `if` logic needed. Additionally, you can use this XSLT script in other languages (PHP, Java, C#, etc.)

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file to be referenced in Python)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFROM: COPY DOC AS IS -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>    
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- REMOVE NAMESPACE PREFIXES, ADD DOC NAMESPACE -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">    
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL
doc = et.parse('Input.xml')
xsl = et.parse('XSLT_Script.xsl')

# CONFIGURE AND RUN TRANSFORMER
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)    
result = transform(doc)

# OUTPUT RESULT TREE TO FILE
with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
  <command>
    <check>
      <check>
        <id>ex61-irnic</id>
        <id>ex999-irnic</id>
        <authInfo>
          <pw>1487441516170712</pw>
        </authInfo>
      </check>
    </check>
    <clTRID>TEST-12345</clTRID>
  </command>
</epp>
```