# ansible xml module - set namespace & namespaced elements

Tags: xml, ansible

I need to change the following xml

```xml
<network>
  <name>docker-machines</name>
  <uuid>ea91ff7c-aa2b-4fa9-b59d-d1fae70285ad</uuid>
  ...
</network>
```

to

```xml
<network xmlns:dnsmasq='http://libvirt.org/schemas/network/dnsmasq/1.0'>
  <name>docker-machines</name>
  <uuid>ea91ff7c-aa2b-4fa9-b59d-d1fae70285ad</uuid>
  ...
  <dns>
    <forwarder addr='5.1.66.255'/>
  </dns>
  <dnsmasq:options>
    <dnsmasq:option value='dhcp-option=option:ntp-server,10.10.14.1'/>
  </dnsmasq:options>
</network>
```

I have successfully managed to set the `<dns><forwarder>` elemnent using this:

```yaml
- name: Set resolver for docker-machines network
  xml:
    path: /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/docker-machines.xml
    xpath: /network/dns
    set_children:
      - forwarder:
          addr: 8.8.8.8
```

Unfortunately, creating the namespaced elements does not seem to be that easy.
For example, I have tried this:

```yaml
- name: Set ntp server for docker-machines network dhcp
  xml:
    path: /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/docker-machines.xml
    xpath: /network/dnsmasq:options/dnsmasq:option
    namespaces:
      dnsmasq: http://libvirt.org/schemas/network/dnsmasq/1.0
    attribute: value
    value: "dhcp-option=option:ntp-server,10.10.14.1"
```

...but it does the correctly set the namespace on `<network>` and instead creates weird `<ns0:>` elements.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Is `network` really your root XML node or is it just a reduction of your XML to have a [mre]?

Comment: If this is really your root node, I am afraid it looks like the lxml library used by Ansible is not really able of adding a namespace to the root node, see the related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11350061/2123530

Comment: Yep, it's the root node. This comment (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38584814/1306186) seems to suggest that with newer lxml it's quite easy. Not sure how to do it with the ansible module though.

Comment: But this is not used anywhere in Ansible's code as you can see by yourself: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/xml.py

Comment: Yep, you're right. Seems like it's not possible with the xml ansible module as of today. Guess I'll have to use the replace module instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try a powershell script using Xml Linq

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq
using assembly System.IO

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"


$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$network = $doc.Root
$dnsmasq = [System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace]::Get('http://libvirt.org/schemas/network/dnsmasq/1.0')
$attribute = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.Xnamespace]::Xmlns + 'dnsmasq', 'http://libvirt.org/schemas/network/dnsmasq/1.0')
$network.Add($attribute)

$dns = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('dns'))
$network.Add($dns)

$forwarder = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('forwarder'))
$dns.Add($forwarder)

$addr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('addr'), '5.1.66.255')
$forwarder.Add($addr)

$options = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($dnsmasq + [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('options'))
$network.Add($options)

$option = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($dnsmasq + [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('option'))
$options.Add($option)

$value = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('value'), 'dhcp-option=option:ntp-server,10.10.14.1')
$option.Add($value)

$doc.Save($outputFilename)
```

Comment: That's nice, but does not help me in my situation (using ansible for linux machines).

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux?view=powershell-7.3